# How to download all files from MinIO bucket in python by only using bucket name .....& no file name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I need to download all the files from the MinIO bucket into the certain local folder Dir. But, I do not have the names of the files which is inside that bucket.

Answer (score 10):

even if don`t have name of bucket u can use bellow:

```
client = Minio(
    "storage_address",
    access_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    secret_key="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
)

for bucket in client.list_buckets():
    for item in client.list_objects(bucket.name,recursive=True):
        client.fget_object(bucket.name,item.object_name,item.object_name)
```

`recursive=True` will return all folders with files

`fget_object` will save files and directory as saved in minio

i u want just one special bucket u can just remove first for loop and replace `bucket.name` with your special bucket name